# Refresh attribute table from Python in QGIS 2

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

Attributes values are changed in a Python plug-in (QGIS 2.14/18) when the user clicks on the canvas. The opened view of the attribute table of the changed feature does not show the changed value even if the *reload table* icon is selected, only if I close and reopen the attribute table. While the info tool show the new correct value.
How can I force the attribute table window to refresh?
The attribute is changed like this:

```
layer.startEditing()
layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(...)
layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing to the layer.changeAttributeValue() solved my problem:

```
layer.startEditing()
layer.changeAttributeValue(...)
layer.commitChanges()
```